# Python 3 - intersection of multiple dictionary key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key, intersection

below is my code, any one can help me to optimize the process by using python 3 build-in library function ?

```
Dict1 = {'ky1':1, 'ky2':2,'ky_3':3}
Dict2 = {'ky1':4, 'ky2':5,'ky_4':6}
Dict3 = {'ky2':7, 'ky3':8,'ky_5':9}
D = [Dict1,Dict2,Dict3]
Keys_list = []
for i in D:
   tmp = list(i.keys())
   Keys_list.append(tmp)
Output = list(set.intersection(*map(set,Keys_list)))
```

My *Dict1, Dict2, Dict3*  is large dictionary 
thanks

Comment: In your above example what do you want as output?

Answer (score 3):

If you just want the list of all keys in all of the dictionaries, you can use `dict.viewkeys()` (For Python 2.7) or `dict.keys()` in Python 3.x , to get the dictionary view object, and then intersect them.

Example for Python 3.x -

```
>>> Dict1 = {'ky1':1, 'ky2':2,'ky_3':3}
>>> Dict2 = {'ky1':4, 'ky2':5,'ky_4':6}
>>> Dict3 = {'ky2':7, 'ky3':8,'ky_5':9}
>>>
>>> Dict1.keys() & Dict2.keys() & Dict3.keys()
{'ky2'}
>>> list(Dict1.keys() & Dict2.keys() & Dict3.keys())
['ky2']
```

For Python 2.7 use `Dict1.viewkeys()` , etc, instead of `.keys()` .

---

If you have a list of dictionaries , one way to do this in one line using `functools.reduce()` function, would be -

```
>>> ld = [{'ky1':1, 'ky2':2,'ky_3':3},{'ky1':4, 'ky2':5,'ky_4':6},{'ky2':7, 'ky3':8,'ky_5':9}]
>>> res = list(reduce(lambda x, y: x & y.keys() , ld))
>>> res
['ky2']
```

Similar logic, using for loop -

```
>>> ld = [{'ky1':1, 'ky2':2,'ky_3':3},{'ky1':4, 'ky2':5,'ky_4':6},{'ky2':7, 'ky3':8,'ky_5':9}]
>>> res = ld.pop()
>>> for d in ld:
...     res = res & d.keys()
...
>>> list(res)
['ky2']
```

Comment: Dear Anand S Kumar, thank for the suggestion, but i have multiple dictionary (said size N), and each dictionary with (many keys, said-10k), so how to address the problem ? thanks,

Comment: How are the dictionaries stored?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly, you're looking for the intersecting keys amongst all three dictionaries, right?

If that is the case, you only need to iterate over one of them, and the process is simple.

```
isect = [i for i in Dict1 if all(i in d for d in (Dict1,Dict2,Dict3))]

print(isect)
```

The list comprehension iterates over one dict, and each item is looked up in all three dicts. If it is present, it will be added to the list. You'll get:

```
['ky2']
```

as the output.

Comment: Dear Renae Lider, thank in advance for the suggestion, but i have multiple dictionary (said size N), and each dictionary with (many keys, said-10k), so how to address the problem ? thanks,

Comment: @ChinLim Dictionary lookup is an ***O(1)*** operation (average). You don't have to worry about size. ***O(n)*** is the worst case.

Comment: You don't need to check whether `i in d` for Dict1, as you already know it's true, because you iterate `i in Dict1`, so you can omit Dict1 from the last tuple.